# FM Radio is ruining my audio. How do I stop this?

Tags: audio, fm-radio

So after noticing the new app icon for the FM app in nougat I decided to give it a look. I listened to radio through my speakers AND my headphones and then exited the app to watch YouTube.

All of the dialogue in the videos are muffled but background music and other songs are just fine. This is also the problem in Google play movies.

I'm certain its the FM radio app messing with equalization. How do I fix this or reset audio settings? I've tried force stopping the FM app as well as disabling it (can't uninstall because it's a default app)

Comment: Could you mention the device model? (not all device has FM support). OTOH, the muffled dialogue could be an indicator of [phase cancellation](https://www.sageaudio.com/blog/pre-mastering-tips/phase-cancellation.php) that often happens on mono-speaker such as a smartphone (my Nexus 5 sometimes have this issue on certain YouTube videos), though it's still weird if it happens on *all* dialogue.

Comment: It is a Moto G4. Not sure exactly the model#